# How to write exception for a loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

```
create or replace PROCEDURE BBVA_SP_MIGRATE_CEG 
(
    --parameter pass
    x_migration_status          OUT         varchar2    
) AS 
    --variable declarations
    v_contract_number                       kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu%type;
    v_customer_code                         kndtcct.tcct_cncctco%type;
    v_customer_name                         varchar2(50);
    v_customer_number                       varchar2(50);
    v_account_number                        varchar2(50);
    v_contact_name                          varchar2(50);
    v_phone_number                          varchar2(25);
    v_email_id                              varchar2(50);
    v_connection_type                       varchar2(50);
    v_LBX_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT2                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT3                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT4                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT5                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT6                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT7                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT8                      varchar2(10);
    v_LBX_OUT9                      varchar2(10);
    v_STOPFILE_IN1                  varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT2                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT3                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT4                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT5                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT6                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT7                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT8                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_OUT9                      varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN1                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN2                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN3                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN4                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN5                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN6                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN7                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN8                       varchar2(10);
    v_ARP_IN9                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT2                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT3                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT4                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT5                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT6                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT7                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT8                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_OUT9                      varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN1                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN2                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN3                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN4                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN5                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN6                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN7                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN8                       varchar2(10);
    v_ACH_IN9                       varchar2(10);
    v_ANL822FILE_OUT1               varchar2(10);
    v_DEPOSITRACKFILE_OUT1          varchar2(10);
    v_EDI_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_CDA_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_BAI_OUT1                      varchar2(10);
    v_ICL_IN1                       varchar2(10);
    v_RECONFILE_OUT1                varchar2(10);
    v_SUSPENDCARDFILE_IN1           varchar2(10);
    V_ceg_record_found              varchar2(1);
    v_REC_NUMBER                    number;
    V_BANKCODE                      varchar2(25);
    v_status                        varchar2(10); 
    v_timestamp                     TIMESTAMP(6):=systimestamp;
    v_tx                  VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_sysdate             DATE := SYSDATE;
    v_tz                  varchar2(2000);
    v_num_err             exception;
BEGIN 
  v_tx:=to_char(v_timestamp,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM');
  v_tz:=to_char(v_sysdate, 'DD-MON-RR');

  x_migration_status:='FAIL';
  V_ceg_record_found:='N';

<<outer_loop>>
for in_rec_number IN 1..500 LOOP

SELECT  CUSTOMERNAME, 
        CUSTOMERNUMBER,
        ACCOUNTNUMBER,
              CONTACTNAME,
              CONTACTPHONE,
              CONTACTEMAIL, 
              CONNECTIONTYPE,
              LBX_OUT1,
              LBX_OUT2,
              LBX_OUT3,
              LBX_OUT4,
              LBX_OUT5,
              LBX_OUT6,
              LBX_OUT7,
              LBX_OUT8,
              LBX_OUT9,
              STOPFILE_IN1,
              ARP_OUT1,
              ARP_OUT2,
              ARP_OUT3,
              ARP_OUT4,
              ARP_OUT5,
              ARP_OUT6,
              ARP_OUT7,
              ARP_OUT8,
              ARP_OUT9,
              ARP_IN1,
              ARP_IN2,
              ARP_IN3,
              ARP_IN4,
              ARP_IN5,
              ARP_IN6,
              ARP_IN7,
              ARP_IN8,
              ARP_IN9,
              ACH_OUT1,
              ACH_OUT2,
              ACH_OUT3,
              ACH_OUT4,
              ACH_OUT5,
              ACH_OUT6,
              ACH_OUT7,
              ACH_OUT8,
              ACH_OUT9,
              ACH_IN1,
              ACH_IN2,
              ACH_IN3,
              ACH_IN4,
              ACH_IN5,
              ACH_IN6,
              ACH_IN7,
              ACH_IN8,
              ACH_IN9,
              ANL822FILE_OUT1,
              DEPOSITRACKFILE_OUT1,
              EDI_OUT1,
              CDA_OUT1,
              BAI_OUT1,
              ICL_IN1,
              RECONFILE_OUT1,
              SUSPENDCARDFILE_IN1,
              'Y', 
        CEG_ID,
        BANKCODE,
        CEG_STATUS

INTO 

    v_customer_name,                            
    v_customer_number,                          
    v_account_number,                           
    v_contact_name,                         
    v_phone_number,                             
    v_email_id,                                 
    v_connection_type,                      
    v_LBX_OUT1,                     
    v_LBX_OUT2,                     
    v_LBX_OUT3,                     
    v_LBX_OUT4,                     
    v_LBX_OUT5,                     
    v_LBX_OUT6,                     
    v_LBX_OUT7,                     
    v_LBX_OUT8,                     
    v_LBX_OUT9,                     
    v_STOPFILE_IN1,                 
    v_ARP_OUT1,                     
    v_ARP_OUT2,                     
    v_ARP_OUT3,                     
    v_ARP_OUT4,                     
    v_ARP_OUT5,                     
    v_ARP_OUT6,                     
    v_ARP_OUT7,                     
    v_ARP_OUT8,                     
    v_ARP_OUT9,                     
    v_ARP_IN1,                      
    v_ARP_IN2,                      
    v_ARP_IN3,                      
    v_ARP_IN4,                      
    v_ARP_IN5,                      
    v_ARP_IN6,                      
    v_ARP_IN7,                      
    v_ARP_IN8,                      
    v_ARP_IN9,                      
    v_ACH_OUT1,                     
    v_ACH_OUT2,                     
    v_ACH_OUT3,                     
    v_ACH_OUT4,                     
    v_ACH_OUT5,                     
    v_ACH_OUT6,                     
    v_ACH_OUT7,                     
    v_ACH_OUT8,                     
    v_ACH_OUT9,                     
    v_ACH_IN1,                      
    v_ACH_IN2,                      
    v_ACH_IN3,                      
    v_ACH_IN4,                  
    v_ACH_IN5,                      
    v_ACH_IN6,                      
    v_ACH_IN7,                      
    v_ACH_IN8,                      
    v_ACH_IN9,                      
    v_ANL822FILE_OUT1,                  
    v_DEPOSITRACKFILE_OUT1,          
    v_EDI_OUT1,                     
    v_CDA_OUT1,                     
    v_BAI_OUT1,                     
    v_ICL_IN1,                  
    v_RECONFILE_OUT1,       
    v_SUSPENDCARDFILE_IN1,          
    v_CEG_RECORD_FOUND,
  v_REC_NUMBER,
  V_BANKCODE,
  V_Status

FROM    t_ceg_migration
WHERE
       upper(CEG_STATUS) = 'RECEIVED'  and   
       in_rec_number     = to_number(CEG_ID);  

IF v_CEG_RECORD_FOUND = 'Y' THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (in_rec_number);

--   get next sequence numbers
V_CONTRACT_NUMBER   :=  tctc_cncclipu_seq.nextval;
V_CUSTOMER_CODE := tcct_cncctco_seq.nextval;

--then inserts into other tables, not relevant to the exception--

x_migration_status := to_char(v_contract_number);


UPDATE t_Ceg_migration
set CEG_status = 'IMPORTED' 
where
       upper(CEG_STATUS) = 'RECEIVED'  and   
       in_rec_number     = to_number(CEG_ID);        

end if; -- ceg_record_found
```

This is where i put the exception after all the updates are supposed to take place for the other tables affected by this procedure.

```
 BEGIN
    IF v_rec_number > 500 THEN
    RAISE v_num_err;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_num_err THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Error: Try Again');
    End;

    end LOOP outer_loop;
    END BBVA_SP_MIGRATE_CEG;
```

where would the exception go to ensure valid records are displayed before running the exception?

Comment: Can you show some more of your procedure for context?

Comment: Two line of source isn't enough. Please show your complete procedure and describe data for it.

Comment: variable dec: x_migration_status          OUT   varchar2
    
) AS 
    
 --variable declarations

 v_contract_number                      kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu%type;
 v_customer_code                 kndtcct.tcct_cncctco%type;
 v_customer_name                      varchar2(50);
 v_customer_number                       varchar2(50);
 v_account_number                     varchar2(50);

Comment: Body:BEGIN 

v_tx:=to_char(v_timestamp,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM');
v_tz:=to_char(v_sysdate, 'DD-MON-RR');

x_migration_status:='FAIL';
V_ceg_record_found:='N';

<<outer_loop>>
for in_rec_number IN 1..500 LOOP



SELECT  CUSTOMERNAME, 
        CUSTOMERNUMBER,
        ACCOUNTNUMBER,
     CONTACTNAME,
     CONTACTPHONE,

Comment: FROM    t_ceg_migration
WHERE
       upper(CEG_STATUS) = 'RECEIVED'  and   
       in_rec_number     = to_number(CEG_ID);  
         
IF v_CEG_RECORD_FOUND = 'Y' THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (in_rec_number);
    
--   get next sequence numbers
V_CONTRACT_NUMBER   :=  tctc_cncclipu_seq.nextval;
V_CUSTOMER_CODE := tcct_cncctco_seq.nextval;

Comment: x_migration_status := to_char(v_contract_number);


UPDATE t_Ceg_migration
set CEG_status = 'IMPORTED' 
where
       upper(CEG_STATUS) = 'RECEIVED'  and   
       in_rec_number     = to_number(CEG_ID);
         

end if; -- ceg_record_found

end LOOP outer_loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR: CHECK YOUR DATA');
  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20002, 'ERROR: CHECK YOUR DATA AND TRY AGAIN');

END BBVA_SP_MIGRATE_CEG;

Comment: Sorry for the messy formatting but the question i was trying to get to was this is a migration procedure where we get column data from an xcel file and if certain conditions are met other tables get updated with new information. Lets say this migration table has 250 records that need to run through the loop to satisfy the conditions. What is happening is even though this migration table now has 5 records, running the procedure is just outputting the error and not the 5 records that are actually available for output.

Comment: Please put code and significant new information into the question, not as comments.

Comment: There's an `edit` button underneath the question. Please use it to edit your question, adding in the code for your procedure. In addition, please read through [How Do I Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the Markdown Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks.

Comment: Is this your full code? It will not work, because at `SELECT` you miss the `INTO` clause.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A small tip to make your questions easier to follow (and get more answers) format them correctly and remove all code which is not needed. There is absolutely no reason to show 100 variables if all you care is a unrelated construct.

Answer (score 3):

You've put the exception handler at the end, which means once it runs into an exception, it exits the loop and is handled at the exception block in the end. If you want the process to continue, then add the exception handler local to the SELECT statement in the loop.

```
PROCEDURE bbva_sp_migrate_ceg(x_migration_status OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS
  v_contract_number kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu%TYPE;
  v_customer_code kndtcct.tcct_cncctco%TYPE;
  v_customer_name   VARCHAR2(50);
  v_customer_number VARCHAR2(50);
  v_account_number  VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  v_tx:=To_char(v_timestamp,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM');
  v_tz:=To_char(v_sysdate, 'DD-MON-RR');
  x_migration_status:='FAIL';
  v_ceg_record_found:='N';
  <<outer_loop>>
  FOR in_rec_number IN 1..500
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT customername,
             customernumber,
             accountnumber,
             contactname,
             contactphone,
      FROM   t_ceg_migration
      WHERE  upper(ceg_status) = 'RECEIVED'
      AND    in_rec_number = to_number(ceg_id);

      IF v_ceg_record_found = 'Y' THEN
        dbms_output.Put_line (in_rec_number); -- get next sequence numbers
        V_CONTRACT_NUMBER := tctc_cncclipu_seq.nextval; 
        V_CUSTOMER_CODE := tcct_cncctco_seq.nextval;
        x_migration_status := To_char(v_contract_number);

        UPDATE t_ceg_migration
        SET    ceg_status = 'IMPORTED'
        WHERE  upper(ceg_status) = 'RECEIVED'
        AND    in_rec_number = to_number(ceg_id);

      END IF; -- ceg_record_found
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line ('No data found for: '
      || v_contract_number);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line ('Error for : '
      || v_contract_number);
      dbms_output.Put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    END
  END LOOP outer_loop;
END bbva_sp_migrate_ceg;
```

This way, if there's some error for a specific iteration of the loop, the exception is trapped, handled, error messages written out to the buffer and then it moves on to the next iteration of the loop

On a related note, it's highly recommended you write out the errors to a table than to the buffer/

Comment: @AlexPoole Woops, yeh meant to remove them earlier but forgot.